# API google analytics v3.0 : avec OAuth 2.0,

Tags: api, google-analytics

I'm trying to install but I get the following error:
`400`. That’s an error.

`Error: redirect_uri_mismatc`h

```
Application: Google analitycs
You can email the developer of this application at: sextoysunivers@gmail.com
The redirect URI in the request: http://sextoysunivers.com/modules/gapi/oauth2callback.php did not match a registered redirect URI
```

I have tried for all shops tab, individually, with the number after the p in my google analytics browser, and with the UA code getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the redirect_uri in the Google Developer Console. After you log in click on APIs & auth, then Credentials and enter your redirect_uri into the redirect_URIs text-area